# Где лежат стандарные картинки JTree Java

Tags: java, swing

Создаю программу на Java. Рисую Jtree - дерево. Для родительских элементов - он подставляет значок папок, а для дочерних элементов - значок файла.

Вопрос. Где лежат данные стандартные картинки icons? Используемая ОС на всякий случай WinXP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В директории JRE (`C:\Java\your.jre.dir`) есть библиотека `resources.jar` с пакетами `javax.swing.plaf` и `com.sun.java.swing.plaf` - посмотрите там. В случае дополнительных L&F комплектов надо смотреть, конечно, в соответствующих jar-файлах.

Comment: Спасибо. Я видимо плохо до этого там смотрел.
Путь к картинкам: путь_к_resources.jar\javax\swing\plaf\metal\icons\ocean